# Least periodic cyclic binary words

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a regular polygon, some vertices of which are labeled with symbol '$0$' and others are labeled with '$1$'.

Consider a set $S$ of rotations of the polygon with the following property: for each vertex $v$  there exists a rotation from $S$ taking some vertex $w$ with label '$1$' to $v$.

Define '**level of periodicity**' to be the minimal possible number of rotations in $S$.

**Examples**:

Level of periodicity of cyclic string '01010101' is equal to $2$ (minimal set of rotations consists of identity rotation and cyclic shift by one position clockwise)

Level of periodicity of '1000000000' is $10$ (since there's only one '1', you'll need 10 rotations to put that '1' to each position)

Level of periodicity of '0111111111' is $2$

---

Last two examples show that my made-up measure is not really perfectly sound, so, let's use it only for $2n$-digit-long **strings with $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones.**

---

Of course, for any cyclic binary string with $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones, level of periodicity is not greater than $n+1$ (identity rotation takes all 1's to 1's, then add $n$ rotations to take first '1' to each '0')
So, among all strings with $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones, there exist '**least periodic**' strings (that is, with the highest possible level of periodicity)

**Question 1**.  Is it true that for any string with $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones, its level of periodicity is less than or equal to $\sqrt{2n} + 1 $?

**Comment for question 1:**

Denote by $a_0$ the maximal number of consecutive '0's  and by $a_1$ the maximal number of consecutive '1's in a string. Denote by $k$ the level of periodicity of the string.

Then $k \leq \frac{2n}{a_1} + 1$ (take $a_1$ consecutive $1$'s and put them to each place with $\lceil\frac{2n}{a_1}\rceil$ rotations)

Also, $k \leq a_0 + 1 $ (consider rotations by $0, 1, 2, 3, ..., a_0$ positions clockwise: since there are no more than $a_0$ consecutive zeroes, any '0' will be image of some '1' under some aforementioned rotation.)

So, $(k-1)^2 \leq 2n \cdot \frac{a_0}{a_1}$

If $a_0 \leq a_1$, then that gives $k \le \sqrt{2n} + 1$.
If $a_0 \ge a_1$, well, that train of thought doesn't work. But, when considering $a_0$, we only considered one cyclic generator of the rotation group. We could try another, that is, choose $t$ such that $gcd(t,2n)=1$ and define $a_{0,t}$ to be the maximal number of 'consecutive' '0's, where 'consecutive' means that they differ by consecutive multiples of $t$. (For example, in '010101010101' there are 6 zeroes that differ by multiples of 2)

So, actually for any $t$ (and there are $\varphi(2n)$ possible choices of $t$) we would have $k \leq a_{0,t}$. Should any $t$ have property $a_{0,t} \leq a_1$, the claim will be proven. That is why I think that answer to question 1 is probably positive.

**Question 2.** (very hard, very interesting). How many 'least periodic' cyclic binary words with $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones are there? 'Least periodic' means 'having maximal level of periodicity for given n'.

**Comment for question 2:**
I don't know precise upper bound for level of periodicity, so I certainly cannot say anything here. Programmatic solution for low $n$'s would be interesting enough to see.